# Collecting and editing data using SharePoint Online

Tags: office-365, export

I need some guidance on the best way to collect and edit data on a SharePoint Online Office 365 system.

There will be multiple users entering and updating the data online. The company does not want to add a lot of access licenses so I'm wondering if excel can be used to accumulate the data in a SharePoint list and retrieve it online to add / edit / update the information. I need to analyze and report the data so I was wondering if I could use access to do that.

I don't know the best way to approach this and wanted some input.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Site Collection Audit log Report under Site Collection Administration. The screen shots give you an idea of what you will be getting:

[image]

[image]